# What does 何でしょうか mean?

Tags: words

What does that mean in the dialogue below.

> すみません。質問があります。
>
> **何でしょうか**。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a polite way of saying 何ですか

でしょう can have other meanings, but in this case it just means です。